# Crash when accessing array

Tags: ios, crash, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have the following weird stacktrace:

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x26ec2e3f __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x34570c8b objc_exception_throw + 38
2  CoreFoundation                 0x26dd7c49 -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]
3  My App                         0x00040363 -[DocumentPageViewController pageAtIndex:] (DocumentPageViewController.m:48)
```

The crash happens in:

```
- (DocumentPage *)pageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return self.pages[index];
}
```

Last, `pages` is defined as:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *pages;
```

I understand that the root cause for the crash would be I'm trying to access an item at an index out of range. However, why is the stack trace involving `removeObjectAtIndex` which I never call?

Thanks!

Comment: The new `[]` notation kind of rattles through the code of the related classes -- not always a well-defined method.  Presumably that's where the error was diagnosed.

Comment: Any update on this post ? why is it showing -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:] rather than showing -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]